# Dynamc Fields - Post object ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**My Model**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Person[] people)
    {
        foreach (var p in people)
            // Do Something
        return View();
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
```

{

```
<div id="form"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addItem">New Person</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
```

}

**My Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addItem").click(addField);
            addField(); 
        });

        function addField() {
            var html = "Name: <input type='text' name='people[]' />";
            $("#form").append(html);
        }
</script>
```

I need to post the inserted data from forms to controller, but dont work...
how can i do that?

i read about binding to model arrays and i did this above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Ajax  us will need to change your Form from pOst to allow JQuery to do this
use $('#Form').Serialize() to get all your data and it should convert into teh C# list of Person
if that does not work try to manually create the object and post it

```
 $.ajax({
            url: URL + 'Person/Save',
            type: 'POST',

            data:  $('#Form').Serialize()

            success: function (data) {
            },

            error: function (e, data) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: i did with this @Html.TextBox("Person[0].Name")..
But i cant put this HtmlHelper inside of my var html like: 
var html = @Html.TextBox("Person[0].Name")

When i press the button to add this new textbox, nothing happens...
How can i create Html.TextBox Dynamically?

Comment: its corret this: 
var html = "Name: <input type='text' name='people[]' />";
i only forgot people[0]
thks for your time :)